# Time Varying Magnetic Field and Electric field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Say,there is a current-carrying loop which enters into a time-varying Magnetic field with some velocity. Now, As Magnetic field is varying, there would be a change in magnetic flux and hence, emf would be induced in the loop by Faraday's law. Since, emf is induced, there is a net Electric Field. Now, the motion of the loop would be due to both the Magnetic field and the electric field. Now, would the motion of the loop be different if the loop enters into a uniform magnetic field and uniform Electric field acting together?

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. There is a current carrying loop which is moving inside a changing magnetic field. There is a changing magnetic flux; therefore, an emf is induced. Then?

Comment: So, How will its motion be compared with another case when there is a uniform Magnetic and Electric Field acting on it?